# How to get css animation to scale to appropriate screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an animation for a webpage I'm tinkering with at the moment. I want the animation of a ball to start from the bottom of the screen, go to the middle, then expand to the whole page. I'm having a problem when it comes to the expanding part. When it expands since I'm using transform: scale it expands beyond the width and height of the viewport causing me to scroll. How is it possible to make it fit into the viewport and not having to scroll. I tried putting it in a  container and putting overflow:hidden but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ballcopy.css">
        <meta name="veiwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
             <div class="ball"></div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

````
    *, *::after, *::before {box-sizing: inherit;}

html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

.ball{
    background-color: #eb8c28; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    animation: rise;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rise{
    0%{
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    50%{
        border-radius: 50%;
        transform:translateY(-400px);
    }

    75%{
        border-radius: 40%;
    }

    80%{
        border-radius: 30%;
    }

    90%{
        border-radius:20%;
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(20,20);
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

this fixes it so that your animation doesn't overflow and make you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

For `overflow: hidden` to work on `main` you need to set `position: relative` and a `height`:

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ball {
  background-color: #eb8c28;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  animation: rise;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rise {
  0% {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 40%;
  }
  80% {
    border-radius: 30%;
  }
  90% {
    border-radius: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(20, 20);
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="ball"></div>
</main>
```

Or you could set `overflow: hidden` on the body:

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ball {
  background-color: #eb8c28;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  animation: rise;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rise {
  0% {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 40%;
  }
  80% {
    border-radius: 30%;
  }
  90% {
    border-radius: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(20, 20);
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="ball"></div>
</main>
```

Also, it's a good idea to set `transform: translateY` to a relative value so it's scalable to different screen-sizes as well, i.e. `transform: translateY(-100%)`

Comment: Great, thank you for the input, ran just what I wanted.

Comment: Just a quick question, let's say I wanted to have other elements on the page scrollable since the body would be overflow: hidden. is there any way I can put this animation in a container and it still work?

Comment: No problem @AlejandroVargas. If you set the containers height and `position: relative; overflow: hidden` it should work